# How to get VSCode default dark theme with Monokai syntax highlighting

Tags: themes, visual-studio-code

I prefer the Monokai themes syntax highlighting way more over any other theme, but I absolutely hate the general poopy brown background colours on the editor, sidebar, toolbar etc.
I've been trying to combine the syntax highlighting colours of Monokai with the background colours Default Dark. I've tried doing it 2 ways:

1. Selecting Monokai theme and editing the background colours (in `settings.json`)
2. Selecting Default dark theme and editing the token colours (in `settings.json`)
3. Finding a Monokai extension while using Default dark theme

My issues are that I can't find a file with all the hex colours of every element for the Default dark theme or the Monokai theme, making it difficult to change the `settings.json` in the way I want.

The top few Monokai extensions change things in ways that I don't want, some of the text highlighting is different, some even change fonts in ways that I don't want

I think the best way to incorporate what I want is my having the Monokai theme selected and then changing the background colours in the `settings.json`, but as I said, I can't find a resource that lists all the hex colours of every single resource in the Default dark theme. I think I can find all the syntax required to define the elements colours (just on the VSCode documentation), it's the actual hex colours that I can't find.

Comment: create a theme extension that uses the Default Dark as base, and only copy the Monokai Textmate colors (can be found in the extension) to this new theme.

Comment: This link to VS Code default theme extensions: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/theme-monokai/themes/monokai-color-theme.json           I'v copy the my favorite colors  to settings.json  in VS Code      (e.g. \n    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editor.background": "#1e1e1e",}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the theme with extension name [`lunadevel.theme-vsmonokai`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lunadevel.theme-vsmonokai); it combines default VSCode Dark theme colors with Monokai on the editor.

Comment: I didn't even realise I had this question still open, so I'm just gonna vote yours as the answer, lucky you!

I did find a different extension that has the theming I want, here is the ID : nonylene.dark-molokai-theme